# How do I prevent text from populating inside my vue component tag?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, visual-studio-code, components

[image: components]

In the image I have the component I created .
But I did not write the text inside the tag.  They all look like text for array methods.  I've never seen this before and I don't know where the text is coming from. I also can't figure out the source, is it coming from vue?  Or is this something to do with VS?
The curious thing is the text does not appear in the component just above .

I tried deleting the extraneous text, since that seems like the simple solution.  However, the text re populates itself. Which makes me wonder if it's something to do with the IDE.

Comment: What VS Code extensions do you have? It could be a misconfigured linter since you say the text appears on save, and usually linters are set up to lint on save.  Try first disabling the linter (if you have one), and then if that doesn't work disable all VS Code extensions.  See if the issue still occurs and if you can narrow it down to a specific extension.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.